# Show that if $f(a) = g(a)$ and $\forall x \in [a,b]: f'(x) > g'(x)$ then for all $x$ in $(a,b]$, $f(x) > g(x)$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Proposition I would like to prove

> Consider arbitrary functions $f,g$ such that
>
> 1. Both are continuous on $[a,b]$
> 2. $f(a) = g(a)$
> 3. $\forall x \in [a,b]: f'(x) > g'(x)$
>
> Show that
>
> $$\forall x \in (a,b]: f(x) > g(x)$$

My initial reasoning:

Since $f(a) = g(a)$ and $f'(a) > g'(a)$, we have

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} > \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(a+h) - g(a)}{h} \implies \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h) - g(a+h)}{h} > 0$$

Which implies that, provided $h$ is sufficiently small, $f(a+h) > g(a+h)$.

The problem now is, how to extend reasoning above to show that inequality holds for all $x \in (a,b]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, assume $h(c)\le 0$ and apply the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In context

FTC:

If $f'(x), g'(x)$ are  integrable then

$\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)dt >\int_{a}^{x}g'(t)dt$;

$f(x)-f(a)>g(x)-g(a)$;

$f(x)>g(x)$, $x \in (a,b].$